# Mesh lab - generate a normal map

Tags: meshlab

in Meshlab, After reducing my poly count on a high res model, can I reimport the high res model (with the reduced version) and compute normal and displacement maps?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

To create a displacement map you can use Filters->Sampling->Haussdorff Distance, choose the sampled mesh to be the high resolution layer and the simplified layer as the target mesh. I leave only the "Sample vertexes[sic]" checked. The samples are stored in the vertex quality.

To get a visual view of the displacement you can use Filters->Color Creation->Colorize by Vertex Quality. The colour range can then be adjusted using the rainbow rabbit button on the toolbar.